# Turning off gdata debug messages when using python-blogger API

Tags: python, gdata-api

I have [following function](https://github.com/dilawar/blogs/blob/master/Blogspot/blogger.py) which initializes the client.

```
import difflib
from gdata import service, GDataEntry
import atom
import sys
import time

"""Initializing instance and login into www.blogger.com"""
    def __init__(self, user, password):
        self.blogger_service = service.GDataService(user, password)
        self.blogger_service.source = 'gv-cl-blogger-updater-1.0'   # Client software name
        self.blogger_service.service = 'blogger'
        self.blogger_service.account_type = 'GOOGLE'
        self.blogger_service.server = 'www.blogger.com'
        self.blogger_service.ssl = True                             # Let's protect connection
        print "[I] Logging into " + self.blogger_service.server + " ..."
        self.blogger_service.ProgrammaticLogin()
        if self.blogger_service.current_token is None:
            print "[E] Unable to login into \"" + self.blogger_service.server + "\""
```

When I run it, it displays the proxy information sent to server on the console. I have proxy-username and password which is also displayed on console (removed here)

```
[I] Logging into www.blogger.com ...
!!!!http://netmon.iitb.ac.in:80
!!!!Basic ZGlsYXdhcnM6Xmt1cnVja2NoZXRyYQ==

!!!!http://netmon.iitb.ac.in:80
```

Is there a flag which I can set so that debugging level can be reduced? I tried `self.blogger_service.debug=False` but it did not change anything.

Comment: Can you update the code with import statements you have used? Also the Logs which you have mentioned, is coming from print statements. Again There is a function called ProgrammaticLogin() which is dumping the next print statements. Need to look into that function which also need to be posted. and also what is your expected behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: @kvivek Added link to repo and import statements.

Comment: The link which is enabled is not what I was looking for it is you main code. which you have written print statements. Can you run your main code in pdb degugger environment and find out where are the unnecessary logs coming from try disabling that. in order to run the code in pdb environment you can use `python -m pdb "full path of python code"`

Comment: @kvivek +1 for -m pdb option. Will let you know what I get. Thanks

Comment: It's a problem with `atom` library. File `http.py` at line no 216 print the proxy info on console.